# Istio bookinfo deploy kiali, error loading graph

Tags: istio-kiali

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4nhJ.png)

istio istio-1.13.2

**kiali-service.yaml**

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
annotations:
kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
{"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"kiali","app.kubernetes.io/instance":"kiali","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"Helm","app.kubernetes.io/name":"kiali","app.kubernetes.io/part-of":"kiali","app.kubernetes.io/version":"v1.45.0","helm.sh/chart":"kiali-server-1.45.0","version":"v1.45.0"},"name":"kiali","namespace":"istio-system"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"http","port":20001,"protocol":"TCP"},{"name":"http-metrics","port":9090,"protocol":"TCP"}],"selector":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"kiali","app.kubernetes.io/name":"kiali"}}}
creationTimestamp: "2022-03-13T14:21:28Z"
labels:
app: kiali
app.kubernetes.io/instance: kiali
app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
app.kubernetes.io/name: kiali
app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kiali
app.kubernetes.io/version: v1.45.0
helm.sh/chart: kiali-server-1.45.0
version: v1.45.0
name: kiali
namespace: istio-system
resourceVersion: "1517"
uid: e71eb0cc-fa77-4ead-b483-cc29f74481c2
spec:
clusterIP: 10.96.129.52
clusterIPs:

- 10.96.129.52
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
- IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
- name: http
  port: 20001
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort: 20001
- name: http-metrics
  port: 9090
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort: 9090
  selector:
  app.kubernetes.io/instance: kiali
  app.kubernetes.io/name: kiali
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
  status:
  loadBalancer: {}

Comment: What does `kubectl get svc -n istio-system` show?

Comment: NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
grafana-67f5ccd9d7-gh5j6               1/1     Running   0          71s
istio-ingressgateway-9c974f69d-q2s4j   1/1     Running   0          5m40s
istiod-dd696df84-44vkm                 1/1     Running   0          5m56s
jaeger-78cb4f7d4b-tdr7b                1/1     Running   0          71s
kiali-c946fb5bc-fl76w                  1/1     Running   0          71s
prometheus-7cc96d969f-zr295            2/2     Running   0          71s